# Como fazer um calculo direto no banco de dados

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de calcular o salário de um professor com base na carga horaria de disciplina que ele leciona, criei um algoritmo em Java para isso, mas no entanto não consigo passar isso para o SQL

Algoritmo em Java

```
public double calcSalario() { //Calcula o salário do professor
    switch (this.getEscolaridade()) {
        case 1:
            this.salario = 20 * this.calcCargaHoraria();
            break;
        case 2:
            this.salario = 23 * this.calcCargaHoraria();
            break;
        default:
            this.salario = 25 * this.calcCargaHoraria();
            break;
    }

    return salario;
}
```

Mas eu não consigo fazer nada próximo disso no SQL, como eu poderia fazer  mesma coisa diretamente no banco de dados?

Essa é a estrutura do meu banco

```
create table pessoa(
    Id_pessoa tinyint not null,
    Nome_pessoa varchar(45) not null,
    Cpf_pessoa varchar(20) not null,
    Sexo_pessoa enum('m', 'f', 'nd') not null,
    primary key(Id_pessoa)
) default charset = utf8;

create table aluno(
    Id_aluno tinyint not null,
    Id_pessoa tinyint not null,
    Score_aluno double,
    Bolsista_aluno tinyint not null,
    primary key(Id_aluno),
    foreign key(Id_pessoa) references pessoa(Id_pessoa)
) default charset = utf8;

create table professor(
    Id_professor tinyint not null,
    Id_pessoa tinyint not null,
    Efetivo_professor tinyint not null,
    Escolaridade_professor tinyint not null,
    Salario_professor double,
    primary key(Id_professor),
    foreign key(Id_pessoa) references pessoa(Id_pessoa)
) default charset = utf8;

create table disciplina(
    Id_disciplina tinyint not null,
    Nome_disciplina varchar(45) not null,
    CargaHoraria_disciplina int not null,
    primary key(Id_disciplina)
) default charset = utf8;

create table curso(
    Id_curso tinyint not null,
    Nome_curso varchar(45) not null unique,
    primary key(Id_curso)
) default charset = utf8;

create table aluno_disciplina(
    Id_aluno tinyint not null,
    Id_disciplina tinyint not null,
    primary key(Id_aluno, Id_disciplina),
    foreign key(Id_aluno) references aluno(Id_aluno),
    foreign key(Id_disciplina) references disciplina(Id_disciplina)
) default charset = utf8; -- Relaciona o aluno com a disciplina que ele está cursando

create table professor_disciplina(
    Id_professor tinyint not null,
    Id_disciplina tinyint not null,
    primary key(Id_professor, Id_disciplina),
    foreign key(Id_professor) references professor(Id_professor),
    foreign key(Id_disciplina) references disciplina(Id_disciplina)
) default charset = utf8; -- Relaciona o professor com a matéria que ele relaciona

create table disciplina_curso(
    Id_disciplina tinyint not null,
    Id_curso tinyint not null,
    primary key(Id_disciplina, Id_curso),
    foreign key(Id_disciplina) references disciplina(Id_disciplina),
    foreign key(Id_curso) references curso(Id_curso)
) default charset = utf8; -- Relaciona a disciplina com o curso
```

Comment: Publique o que faz calcCargaHoraria

Comment: @AbelSouza: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MariaDB? Oracle Database? SQL Server? outro?

Comment: Assim como voce criou uma funcao para calcular a calcCargaHoraria voce pode criar funções nos bancos de dados, depois o resto é só continuar parecido.

Answer (score 1):

Um case when simples resolve seu problema:

```
select 
c.nomeProfessor,
case when c.carga = 1 then
    20 * c.carga_horaria
when = 2 then 
[...]
end as salarioProfessor
from tabelaCargaHoraria c inner join tabelaProfessor p on c.idProfessor=p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

> (...) *Gostaria de calcular o salário de um professor com base na carga horaria de disciplina que ele leciona*, (...)

Eis uma sugestão, que primeiro soma a carga horária de todas as disciplinas que o professor ensina e após calcula o salário.

```
-- código #1
with calcCargaHoraria as (
SELECT PD.Id_professor, sum(D.CargaHoraria_disciplina) as totalCargaHoraria
  from professor_disciplina as PD 
       inner join disciplina as D on D.Id_disciplina = PD.Id_disciplina
  group by PD.Id_professor
)
SELECT P.Id_professor, CH.totalCargaHoraria, 
       case P.Escolaridade_professor
            when 1 then 20 * CH.totalCargaHoraria
            when 2 then 23 * CH.totalCargaHoraria
            else 25 * CH.totalCargaHoraria end as salario
  from Professor as P
       left join calcCargaHoraria as CH on CH.Id_professor = P.Id_professor;
```

No código acima é assumido que um professor não possui mais de uma turma para a mesma disciplina, pela ausência de informações sobre turmas. Mas o usual é que um professor ministre determinada disciplina em uma ou mais turmas. Me parece que o modelo de dados necessita ser reavaliado.

Comment: Muito Obrogado Amigo, era exatamente o que eu queria